# Javascript Regexp - Match Characters after a certain phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering how to use a regexp to match a phrase that comes after a certain match. Like:

```
var phrase = "yesthisismyphrase=thisiswhatIwantmatched";
var match = /phrase=.*/;
```

That will match from the `phrase=` to the end of the string, but **is it possible to get everything after the `phrase=` without having to modify a string**?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You use [capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) (denoted by parenthesis).

When you execute the regex via match or exec function, the return an array consisting of the substrings captured by capture groups. You can then access what got captured via that array. E.g.:

```
var phrase = "yesthisismyphrase=thisiswhatIwantmatched"; 
var myRegexp = /phrase=(.*)/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(phrase);
alert(match[1]);
```

or

```
var arr = phrase.match(/phrase=(.*)/);
if (arr != null) { // Did it match?
    alert(arr[1]);
}
```

Comment: isn't there a way to avoid using that `match[1]` ?

Answer (score 18):

```
phrase.match(/phrase=(.*)/)[1]
```

returns

```
"thisiswhatIwantmatched"
```

The brackets specify a so-called capture group. Contents of capture groups get put into the resulting array, starting from 1 (0 is the whole match).

Comment: It is important to realize the `.match` returns `null` if the match fails, so test for that before trying to get the first index is a good idea. Also, if you have more than one phase in that key=value string you might change the regex to `/phrase=(.*?)(;|$)/` where ; is the delimiter. Further, you could abstract this with a method using the RegEx constructor...

Answer (score 6):

It is not so hard, Just assume your context is :

```
const context = "https://example.com/pa/GIx89GdmkABJEAAA+AAAA";
```

And we wanna have the pattern after `pa/`, so use this code:

```
const pattern = context.match(/pa\/(.*)/)[1];
```

The first item include `pa/`, but for the grouping second item is without `pa/`, you can use each what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let try this, I hope it work

```js
var p = /\b([\w|\W]+)\1+(\=)([\w|\W]+)\1+\b/;
console.log(p.test('case1 or AA=AA ilkjoi'));
console.log(p.test('case2 or AA=AB'));
console.log(p.test('case3 or 12=14'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value after the regex excluding the test phrase, use this:
`/(?:phrase=)(.*)/`

the result will be

```
0: "phrase=thisiswhatIwantmatched" //full match
1: "thisiswhatIwantmatched" //matching group
```