# read/write Windows image tags (keywords)

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, file, exif

[image: Windows image tags in properties]
[image: Windows image tags in status bar]

.

**How can I read/write these *tags* from a file on Windows?**

I'm trying to acheive it in **javascript** and **node.js** but failed to find information in any language at all so I'm looking for any clues.

.

The word *tags* (sometimes called *keywords*) seem to be unfortunately chosen, as it appears to be normally describing any metadata of a file, such as EXIF. Yet in windows you can save such *descriptive-tags* as one of the file *tags*.  To start with - any idea on how are they really called?

I'm aware you can modify them using various programs, eg. in Adobe Bridge they're called *keywords* of a file.

.

*Note: I do realise it's not the best solution of storing file tags. I really just need to work with these, since the image library I'm working with is using them heavily.*

[Edit.1]

@Ben Fortune: Thanks for the clue! Still, [Exif-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif-parser) gives a way to read these tags, however does not allow for writing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to read file metadata using node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091836/is-there-a-way-to-read-file-metadata-using-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answers are:

1. These *Windows tags* are really called **EXIF XPKeywords**. [See the full list here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html)
2. Parsing a file using [Exif Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif-parser) is good for reading, however they come back as decimal ASCII code. Using

   ```
   String.fromCharCode()
   ```

   and looping through the returned integers I managed to get the tags as strings.
3. However, for reading AND writing I ended up going with the [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). Therefore, I'm using

   ```
   function run_cmd(cmd, args, callBack ) {
       var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
       var child = spawn(cmd, args);
       var resp = "";

       child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { resp += buffer.toString() });
       child.stdout.on('end', function() { callBack (resp) });
   } // ()
   ```

   to execute the exiftool as a shell command ([More on spawning shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17466459/3508719))

.

**For reading** I'm passing

```
    run_cmd('exiftool', ['-XPKeywords', myFilepath])
```

to read the XPKeywords tag and

```
    theShellResult.match(/:(.*)/)
```

to filter out only the keywords ([Nicely explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4571568/3508719)).

.

**For writing (appending)** new XPKeywords I'm simply changing the args to:

```
    var writeArg = "-XPKeywords<$XPKeywords " + myNewKeywords
    run_cmd('exiftool', [writeArg, myFilepath])
```

.

I found a way around it but I'd be calm knowing it is not executed through a shell command. Therefore, the question remains open -  Can you suggest a good the interface for reading and writing EXIF tags in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to call external commands. You can use a node module called node-ipct. This module extracts ipct information including XPKeywords.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-iptc