# How to parse specific words after text?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, string-matching

The text I would like to parse always comes in the following pattern:

"Your $22.12 transaction with Amazon.com"

I would like to parse all text after "transaction with " which would be the name of company/store.

Can anybody help with this?
Thank you so much!

---

This question does *not* have a relevant enough answer here : [Javascript Regexp - Match Characters after a certain phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571531/javascript-regexp-match-characters-after-a-certain-phrase?noredirect=1&lq=1) That question is about matching characters after a fixed, exact, constant phrase. The phrase in this question contains **a substring (the $ amount) that varies.** <sub>An answer should explain, in addition to how to get characters after text, how to match a dollar money amount with RegEx.</sub>

Comment: So what have you tried and what was your problem? Was your problem finding the correct RegExp? Was it about using the RegExp? …

Answer (score 0):

This Regular Expression may work:

```regex
Your \$\d+\.\d{2} transaction with (.*)
```

Just make a regex that matches the beginning phrase followed by `(.*)`.

`\d` matches any digit character from 0 to 9.

The plus sign `+` matches 1 or more of what precedes it. `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.

`{2}` matches exactly 2 of something. `\d{2}` matches 2 digits.

`.` matches any character. `*` matches zero or more of what comes before it. So Regex `.*` matches any number of any character, greedily. Wrapping `.*` in parentheses creates a capture group that lets you get the matched text after running the regex on it.

```js
const txt = 'Your $22.12 transaction with Amazon.com'
const regEx = /Your \$\d+\.\d{2} transaction with (.*)/
const matches = txt.match(regEx)
document.write(matches[1])
```

Comment: Why not `Your \$\d+\.\d+`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna Good catch. I’d forgotten about `\d`